# Plotly Update Button to Filter Dataset

Tags: python, plotly

I am brand new to the world of Python and Plotly and have been working on a Capstone project with the following objective:
Create an interactive chart that allows the user to view US Vehicle Sales between 2019-2021
that allows the user to view the data by Body Type, Segment, Year, Make/Brand, and Individual Models.

I have learned how to add buttons using Plotly Express, though I have been having issues with making them toggle the way I want them to. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    segbar = px.bar(segments, x=segments.Month, y=segments.NumSold, color=segments.NumSold,
color_continuous_scale='inferno', custom_data=[segments.Segment, segments.PrimaryBodyType, segments.Month, segments.Year], barmode='group')
segbar.update_traces(hovertemplate='<b>Segment:</b> %{customdata[0]} %{customdata[1]}<br><b>Units Sold:</b> %{y:,.0f}<br>Date: %{customdata[2]} %{customdata[3]}')


segbar.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="dropdown",
            direction="down",
            bgcolor='Dark Blue',
            buttons=list(
                [
                dict(
                    label="(All)",
                    method="update",
                    args=[{"y": segments.NumSold},
                    {"x": segments.Month}],
         ),
            dict(
                label="2021",
                method="update",
                args=[{"y": segments.loc[segments['Year'] == "2021", "NumSold]},
                      {"x": segments.loc[segments['Year] == "2021", "Month"]}]
            )
            ]),
        ), dict(
            type="dropdown",
            direction="down"
    )
], template='plotly_dark')
segbar.show()
```

The default view (first button) seems to be working fine, though when I select the other button to filter by rows with a "Year" value of 2021, this is the output:

[image: Chart2021Filtered]

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty close – you just need to add another set of square brackets around the `pd.Series` you are passing to `"y"` and `"x"` in the `args` key of the dictionaries. To get the example to work, I had to modify your DataFrame slightly, but this should work with your DataFrame.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

segment_data = StringIO("""Segment|PrimaryBodyType|Month|Year|NumSold|MonthNum(Index)|Compact|
A|SUV|January|2021|254391|0|Compact| 
B|SUV|January|2019|249913|0|Midsize| 
C|SUV|January|2021|248762|0|Midsize| 
D|SUV|January|2020|239102|0|Compact| 
E|SUV|January|2020|233614|0|Compact|
""")

segments = pd.read_csv(segment_data, sep="|")
segments["Year"] = segments["Year"].astype(str)

segbar = px.bar(segments, x=segments.Month, y=segments.NumSold, color=segments.NumSold,
color_continuous_scale='inferno', custom_data=[segments.Segment, segments.PrimaryBodyType, segments.Month, segments.Year], barmode='group')
segbar.update_traces(hovertemplate='<b>Segment:</b> %{customdata[0]} %{customdata[1]}<br><b>Units Sold:</b> %{y:,.0f}<br>Date: %{customdata[2]} %{customdata[3]}')


segbar.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="dropdown",
            direction="down",
            bgcolor='Dark Blue',
            buttons=list(
                [
                dict(
                    label="(All)",
                    method="update",
                    args=[{"y": [segments.NumSold]},
                    {"x": [segments.Month]}],
         ),
            dict(
                label="2021",
                method="update",
                args=[{"y": [segments.loc[segments['Year'] == "2021", "NumSold"]]},
                      {"x": [segments.loc[segments['Year'] == "2021", "Month"]]}]
            )
            ]),
        ), dict(
            type="dropdown",
            direction="down"
    )
], template='plotly_dark')
segbar.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. Your solution seemed to help, though when I select the button labeled "2021", only 5 months (January- May) are displayed and the dataframe isn't filtered by year. I'll update the post with the updated code and an image of the chart.